# How to make the left side of the pyramid graph on R be positive

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a pyramid graph on Rstudio and I don't know why the left side of my pyramid is negative(I would like positive values)

code:

```
r piramide, include = FALSE}
label_sexo <- c('0' = "Masculino",'1' = "Feminino")

idades <- base_matriculas_final[,list(matriculados = 
length(unique(id_aluno))),
                                 by = c("vila","sexo_adj","idade")]
base_matriculas_final[,sexo_label := sexo_adj %>% factor(labels = 
label_sexo)]
base_matriculas_final[,idade_5 := (idade %/% 5)*5]

idades_prop <- base_matriculas_final[idade_5 <= 70,
                                     list(N = length(unique(id_aluno))),
                                     by = 
c("sexo_label","vila","idade_5","sexo_adj")]

idades_prop <- idades_prop[,prop := 100*ifelse(sexo_label =="Masculino",
                                               -N/sum(N),
                                               N/sum(N)),
                           by = vila]
max_prop <- idades_prop[,max(abs(prop),na.rm = T)]
max_prop <- ifelse(max_prop > 20, 25, 20)

piramides <-
  lapply(split(idades_prop, by =  "vila"),
         function(data){
           vila_n <- data[,unique(vila)]
           ggplot(data,
                  aes(x = idade_5,y = prop,
              geom_bar(data = subset(data,sexo_adj == 1),
                      stat = "identity") + 
             geom_bar(data = subset(data,sexo_adj == 0),
                      stat = "identity") + 
             geom_text(aes(label = format (prop, digits=2)), 
                       hjust = "outward", size = 2,
                       position = position_dodge(width = 1), check_overlap = 
TRUE) + 
             scale_y_continuous(labels = abs,
                                limits = max_prop*c(-1,1),
                                breaks = seq(-max_prop, max_prop, by = 5)) +  
             scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,120, by = 5)) 
+
             coord_flip() +
             labs(title = vila_n,
                  y = "% de pessoas",
                  x = "Idade (5 em 5 anos)",
                  fill = "Gênero") -> plot_vila
           plot_vila
           })
+  theme_bw()
```

First I thought the problem were the labels, but I think it isn't.

Picture Graph:

[image: 1]

Comment: Try using absolute values for your label geom, i.e.              geom_text(aes(label = format (abs(prop), digits=2)),